# Why can't I get to the "Update time from internet" dialog more easily?

Tags: windows-10, date-time

Here's what I do:

I rightclick the date/time applet in the taskbar and select "Adjust date/time". Then I want to click the "Change" button under "Change date and time", but it's disabled. **Any idea why is it disabled?**

Since that button is disabled, I have to do a workaround:

1. Click "Additional date, time, & regional settings" in that same page
2. Click "Set the time and date"
3. Go to "Internet time"
4. Click "Change settings"

**Note:** My motivation for wanting to manually sync with internet time is that when I boot into Ubuntu and then back into Windows, the time is always several hours off.

Comment: Sounds like you have a group policy or your not logged into as an Administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “Change” button is disabled when “Set time automatically” is enabled. It also does not offer an option to synchronize the time:

[image]

However, your entire approach is flawed. You should instead either configure Ubuntu to have the hardware clock in local time or set Windows to have the hardware clock in UTC.

Refer to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts) on how to do that:

- Change (recent) Ubuntu: `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`
- Change Windows:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
  "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
  ```

However, Windows does not fully support this and may still write the local time to the hardware clock.

Comment: I ran `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` but the problem persists. And I don't want to try the "Change Windows" method, since you say it's unreliable. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check that `/etc/adjtime` has been updated. You may also wish to inspect the `timedatectl status` output. It should generally work. However, I’m afraid there isn’t a universally good solution for this issue. You could look into replacing dual boot with virtual machines.